# Update child object in nested form in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

My current devise config has a user object that has a single table inheritance structure that breaks down into two further user types (one of them is business). The child object of business I am trying to update is called 'supp_forms'. When I try and update the record I get the following error in terminal. I am using the nested_form_for gem to handle my nested forms.

```
Unpermitted parameters: supp_form_attributes
```

However, the parameters being passed through look correct (the data being passed through is the data that I have edited in the form).

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XX", "business"=>{"supp_form_attributes"=>{"work_phone_number"=>"(906) 790-6969 x69696", "business_address"=>"1 XXXX st", "business_postal_code"=>"L0R 1K2", "business_city"=>"Oria", "business_province"=>"ON", "employee_count"=>"5", "id"=>"96"}}, "commit"=>"Update Business"}
```

My update form looks like the following. 
**business_profile.html.erb**

```
<%= nested_form_for @user, url: business_registration_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :supp_form do |supp_form| %>
    <%= supp_form.label :work_phone_number %>
    <%= supp_form.text_field :work_phone_number %>
    <%= supp_form.label :business_address %>
    <%= supp_form.text_field :business_address %>
    <%= supp_form.label :business_postal_code %>
    <%= supp_form.text_field :business_postal_code %>
    <%= supp_form.label :business_city %>
    <%= supp_form.text_field :business_city %>
    <%= supp_form.label :business_province %>
    <%= supp_form.text_field :business_province %>
    <%= supp_form.label :employee_count %>
    <%= supp_form.text_field :employee_count %>
   <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**business.rb**

```
class Business < User
  # Associations
  has_one :supp_form
  has_many :loan_applications
  has_many :transactions
  has_many :listing_information_forms

  # Nested attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :supp_form
end
```

**supp_form.rb**

```
class SuppForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :business
end
```

**supp_forms_controller.rb**

```
class SuppFormsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def edit
      @user = User.current_user
    end 

    def update
      @user = current_user
      @suppform = @user.supp_form
      if @suppform.update_attributes(supp_form_params)
        business_supp_form_path(@user)
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end 

    private

      def supp_form_params
        params.require(:supp_form).permit(:business_id, :title, :loan_agreement_authorization, :first_name, :last_name, :applicant_role, :work_phone_number, :business_address, :business_postal_code,:business_city, :business_name, :years_in_business, :legal_structure, :ownership, :business_industry, :employee_count, :mobile_phone_number, :business_province, :business_country)
      end
end
```

**business_account_controller.rb**

```
class BusinessAccountController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def business_profile
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

**registrations_controller.rb (for businesses)**

```
class Businesses::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params

  def edit
    @user = current_user
    super
  end 

  def update
    @user = current_user
    super
  end

private

  def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :type, :confirmed_at, :business_name, :terms, :railsid, :terms_of_service, supp_form_attributes: [:business_id, :title, :loan_agreement_authorization, :first_name, :last_name, :work_phone_number, :applicant_role, :business_address, :business_postal_code, :business_city, :business_name, :years_in_business, :legal_structure, :ownership, :business_industry, :employee_count, :mobile_phone_number, :business_province, :business_country])}
  end

end
```

Comment: where is `permit(business: [supp_form_attributes])`?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I permit the supp_form_attributes in the registrations_controller in the update_sanitized_params method

Answer (score 2):

Please try to do as following, it works on my side and hope it helpful for you.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << { profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name] }
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: That is for the create object? Or should I put this in the update method of the registrations_controller?

Comment: Yes, you should add this to update method if you need to update.